# How to apply multiple generics in a function using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, generic-programming

I am trying to create a function that will animate a transition between Activity A to Activity B by parsing the context of activity A and the class of activity B. I realised that there will be instances where I wanted to parse information using serialized data classes from one activity. So I created the following function :

```
fun <T, U> changeActivity(activityAContext : Context, activityB: Class<T>, anim1 : Int, anim2 : Int, extras : Map<String, Class<U>>?=null)
        where T : Activity,
              U : Serializable {
    val activity = activityAContext as Activity
    val intent = Intent(activityAContext , activityB)

    if (extras != null) {

        for ((k, v) in extras) {
            intent.putExtra(k, v)
        }
    }

    activity.overridePendingTransition(anim1, anim2)

    finish()
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

However, this doesn't compile with error "Not enough information to infer parameter U". I don't quite understand this is since I specified that type U should be a class that is Serializable. If possible can you please explain why this is happening and how I can solve it?

Comment: Serializable is an interface. You don't extend it but implement it.

Comment: Your code compiles and does work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure you need to use generics here.

You should take advantage of polymorfism and declare the following: Write an extension method for the `Activity` class, so you don't have to pass any context as parameter. By using polymorfism, let the class be form something *that is an `Activity`*, and the `Map` that you're given is a `Map` of `String`, `Serializable` and you'll be more than good.

```
fun Activity.changeActivity(newActivityClass: Class<Activity>, enteringAnimation: Int, exitingAnimation: Int, extras: Map<String, Serializable>?=null) {
        val intent = Intent(this , newActivityClass)

        extras?.let { it.forEach{ pair -> intent.putExtra(pair.key, pair.value)} }

        overridePendingTransition(enteringAnimation, exitingAnimation)

        finish()
        startActivity(intent)
}
```

You may now use this extension function from any other `Activity` as follows:

```
changeActivity(DetailActivity::class.java, R.anim.someAnim, R.anim.someOtherAnim, mapOf(Pair("first", myFancySerializableObject)))
```

In any way, the way I use to set generics in Kotlin is the following

```
fun<T: Activity, U: Serializable> myFancyFunction(firstParam: T, second: U) = Unit
```

### Edit

Just tested the code and trying to call that function ends up not compiling at all because it expects the first argument to **exactly be** the `Class`of `Activity`.

In that case you may use the new declaration as so:

```
fun <A : Activity> Activity.changeActivity(newActivityClass: Class<A>, enteringAnimation: Int, exitingAnimation: Int, extras: Map<String, Serializable>?=null)
```

Or by taking a look at the constructor of an `Intent`

```
public Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls) {
    mComponent = new ComponentName(packageContext, cls);
}
```

You can use  `Class<*>` as the type of the first argument. Without any generics at all.

Comment: Let me know how it goes!